# Firebase Multiple Collection Update

Tags: objective-c, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> Is there a way to update two documents, each in a different
>   collection, in **one** request?

I know you can batch write using `FIRWriteBatch` - this seems to be limited to the *same* collection for any document updates. When trying to attach updates for documents in two different collections:

```
// Just for example
FIRWriteBatch *batch = FIRWriteBatch.new;

[batch updateData:@{@"posts" : @1} forDocument:[self.firebase.usersCollection documentWithPath:@"some_user_id"]];
[batch setData:@{@"test" : @"cool"} forDocument:[self.firebase.postsCollection documentWithPath:@"some_post_id"]];

[batch commitWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);

}];
```

It never executes - the app crashes and I get this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'Provided document reference is from a different Firestore instance.'
```

---

Apparently the batch does not like updates in more than one collection.

- Does anyone know how you can update two documents, each in a different collection, without one failing and the other succeeding?

I want to avoid, for example, successfully setting `posts = 1` for a document in **usersCollection**, while **failing** to write a new document in **postsCollection**.

I understand it's pretty unlikely that one will write while the other fails, but in the case that it **does** happen, I obviously don't want inconsistent data.

---

**NOTE:**

For anyone who cares - I don't know if it ever *will* fail, but as of now I am running the transaction **without** reading the document before updating data... ‍♂️ Cheers to -1 API call!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), which is documented adjacent to batch writes:

> Using the Cloud Firestore client libraries, you can group multiple
>   operations into a single transaction. Transactions are useful when you
>   want to update a field's value based on its current value, or the
>   value of some other field. You could increment a counter by creating a
>   transaction that reads the current value of the counter, increments
>   it, and writes the new value to Cloud Firestore.

You are not limited to a single collection when performing a transaction.  You are just obliged to read the document before you write it:

> A transaction consists of any number of get() operations followed by
>   any number of write operations such as set(), update(), or delete().
>   In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire
>   transaction again. For example, if a transaction reads documents and
>   another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore
>   retries the transaction. This feature ensures that the transaction
>   runs on up-to-date and consistent data.

Comment: I know of the transaction - just trying to avoid that extra read request. Unless transactions are single request items? I know there was a discrepancy with batches and whether they counted as 1 or n-document writes

Comment: Each document read is always going to get billed as a document read, inside or outside a transaction.  There's no way to collapse them in terms of cost of efficiency.  Batch writes are always going to cost a number of writes equal to the number of documents in that batch.

Comment: Right, thought so. Wish it wasn't so but that's what the docs have always said. Last question - do you know if concurrent edits count towards writes as well? Or is that just for the doc read in the transaction? (in case before you finish writing the doc gets written by another client)

Comment: I don't believe transaction retries have an effect on billing, since the write was never actually committed.  You should check the billing page to confirm, or contact Firebase support directly if you need confirmation.